# Uploading an UTF-8 text file in Blackberry

Tags: java, file, blackberry, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to upload an UTF-8 text file to a server in Blackberry. The upload works great but when I check the file in the server it's an ASCII file and what I need is an UTF-8 file.

This is the code that I use when I create the file:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName);
if (!fc.exists()){
    fc.create();
}
long byteOffset = fc.usedSize();
OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream(byteOffset);           
outStream.write(line.getBytes("UTF-8"));
outStream.close();
fc.close();
```

To send the file I use this:

```
public void run (){

    httpConnection = null;
    _connectionURL = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--"; 
    String boundary = "*****";  
    int rc = -1;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {

        _connectionURL = Constants.UPLOAD_URL + getConnectionString();

        httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_connectionURL);
        byte [] postDataBytes = getData();

        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); 
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "BlackBerry");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=*****");                        
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL,"no-cache, no-store, no-transform");           

        os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
        os.write((twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd).getBytes());
        os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fileName +"\"" + lineEnd).getBytes());
        os.write(lineEnd.getBytes());
        os.write(postDataBytes);
        os.write(lineEnd.getBytes());
        os.write((twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd).getBytes());
        os.flush(); 


        // Response
        rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream in = httpConnection.openInputStream();
        int ch;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while( ( ch = in.read() ) != -1 ){
            stringBuffer.append( (char)ch );
        }            
        String responseString = stringBuffer.toString();

        ...

    }catch (IOException ioe){
       ...
    }
}

...

private byte[] getData() throws IOException {
    int _c;
    StringBuffer _stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("UTF-8");
    FileConnection fileForUpload = (FileConnection) Connector.open(Constants.FOLDER_FILES+this.fileName, Connector.READ);
    this.fileInputStream = fileForUpload.openDataInputStream();
    this.postData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    while( (_c = this.fileInputStream.read()) != -1){
        _stringBuffer.append((char)_c);         
    }
    postData.setData(_stringBuffer);
    byte [] _postData = postData.getBytes();
    fileForUpload.close();
    return _postData;
}
```

I guess there is something wrong in *getData()* method or in the *httpConnection* properties, but i don't know what is it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Jon Skeet's answer.

To read byte array from file you can simply use `net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities`:

```
FileConnection fileForUpload = 
        (FileConnection) Connector.open(path, Connector.READ);
InputStream stream = fileForUpload.openInputStream();
byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks Arhimed, I've tried with _IOUtilities.streamToBytes()_ but files are still uploaded in the server in ASCII.

Comment: Well, if you save data to file using `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`, then data is in correct encoding. If later on device side you manipulate with that data only as a byte array, then encoding does not change and server should get it in correct encoding. It could be a server side issue - are you sure server treats the got binary data correctly?

Comment: Solved. The problem was: I was testing with a file that contain only ASCII characters, that's why when I used the `file -ib` command in the server side I always received `charset: us-ascii`  After that, I tried with special characters within the file and the commands result was `charset: utf-8`. By the way, I mark your answer as correct because the way I get the byte array was wrong and yours correct. Thank you Arhimed.

Comment: Well, actually Jon Skeet's answer deserves solution mark just because he was first who explained to you what's wrong. While mine just shows an easy way to do what he suggested. So feel free to move solution to his answer.

Comment: +1, because I think `IOUtilities.streamToBytes()` is really the best solution, for *BlackBerry* Java ... and also for good sportsmanship :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code, which appears twice:

```
while( ( ch = in.read() ) != -1 ){
    stringBuffer.append( (char)ch );
}
```

That's treating each byte as a separate character, effectively in ISO-8859-1.

If you really want to convert the content to text, you should be using an `InputStreamReader` with an encoding of UTF-8, then ideally reading *blocks* of characters (rather than one character at a time).

This isn't helping either:

```
byte [] _postData = postData.getBytes();
```

That will be using the platform default encoding to convert a string to bytes - that's almost *never* what you want.

Given that your `getData` method is trying to read a file *as a byte array*, you shouldn't be converting it to text at all, IMO. If you know the file length beforehand, you should just create a byte array of the right size and repeatedly call `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)`, noting the return value to see how far you've read. If you don't, you can repeatedly read into a smallish buffer, then write the data you've just read into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which you can later get the byte array from.

Additionally, you don't appear to ever close any of your streams - which you should do in `finally` statements, so that the streams are closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: +1 but there is no hole in ISO-8859-1, the `0x80-0x9F` range maps to the C1 control characters of the same unicode code point value.

Comment: @Esailija: Will remove that bit. I'd *thought* it was an actual hole, but I believe that varies between documents you read :(

Comment: Well according to wikipedia, the one with the holes is `ISO 8859-1` (no dash) and the one supplemented with C0 and C1 is `ISO-8859-1` (dash after ISO) :P

Comment: @Esailija: Ah. That's almost certainly where I was confused. (Frankly I don't blame myself too much on this one!)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: +1. I've just posted a simplier way of reading bytes from file on BlackBerry.

Comment: Thanks Jon, nice explanation. Unfortunatly files are still in ASCII on the server side. I even try with @Arhimed answer but nothing change.